# IndexError when iterating my dataset using Dataloader in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I iterated my dataset using Dataloader in PyTorch 0.2 like these:

```
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(...)
data_iter = iter(dataloader)
data = data_iter.next()
```

but IndexError was raised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 193, in <module>
    data_target = data_target_iter.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 201, in __next__
    return self._process_next_batch(batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 221, in _process_next_batch
    raise batch.exc_type(batch.exc_msg)
IndexError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 40, in _worker_loop
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 40, in <listcomp>
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/home/asr4/zhuminxian/adversarial/code/dataset/data_loader.py", line 33, in __getitem__
    return self.X_train[idx], self.y_train[idx]
IndexError: index 4196 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4135
```

I am wondering why the index was out of bounds. Is it the bug of Pytorch?

I tried to run my code again, the same error raised, but at different iteration and with different out-of-bound index.

Comment: Can you try this way: 
data_iter = iter(torch.utils.data.DataLoader(...));
data  = data_iter.next()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is that your [`data.Dataset.__len__`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) was not overloaded properly and in-fact `len(dataloader.dataset)` returns a number larger than `len(self.X_train)`.
Check your implementation of the underlying dataset in `'/home/asr4/zhuminxian/adversarial/code/dataset/data_loader.py'`.